# Django Admin: How to use OneToMany Field inside list_display?

Tags: python, django

When listing the "House" Model inside the django admin panel i want to show all Houses but with the PostalCode inside list_display so i can sort them by postal code. Can i use the existing ForeignKey connection between House and HouseAddress to achieve this?

I found some information on how to list parts of the "Houses" inside the "House Addresses" list view (because it has the foreign key field) but not from the "Houses" list view.

Admin.py

```
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['Name']
    list_display = ['Name']

class HouseAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['PostalCode']

    model = HouseAddress
    list_display = ['PostalCode']
```

Model.py

```
class House(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)




class HouseAddress(models.Model):
    PostalCode = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    AddressInfo = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fa')
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `OneToOneField`?

Comment: I mean one house can only hold one address

Comment: I simplified it a bit in my example above but in my usecase there is several "units" at the same address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve something close to what you need (or at least useful) with `list_filter`, using something like:

```
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['Name']
    list_display = ['Name']
    list_filter = ['fa__PostalCode']
```

This will give you a sidebar where you can click on a postal code and it will filter the houses in that code. `list_filter` will also provide a default sort.

Comment: list_filter did not work for me but i used what you just wrote in your answer inside the search fields which works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I hope, I am getting what you want to do exactly. Below is the image of the end result.

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import House, HouseAddress


@admin.register(House)
class HouseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ['name', 'get_postal_code']

    def get_postal_code(self, obj):
        return ", ".join([qs.postalcode for qs in obj.fa.all()])


@admin.register(HouseAddress)
class HouseAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['postalcode']

    model = HouseAddress
    list_display = ['postalcode']
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the sorting for the postal codes work too?

Comment: Yes, as this custom `list_display'` field is a database field. Use `admin_order_field` on this custom field. Read more [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/)